# Scrolling inside a div also scrolls the content behind it after reaching it's end (Mobile HTML)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have designed a mobile website for a client. A div appears up from the footer and it has a list of categories where I have to give a vertical scroll.

What I want is that when the scroll inside the div ends, the body should not scroll until I close down this div.

Here is a link to my website http://ketchupdesigns.com/jwmobile/

And Here is a picture of that div (opened div under 'kurtis')

[image]

when we scroll inside this div, it reaches it's end and then if we scroll...the body behind it scrolls (As shown in following image)

[image]

Please help if possible.

Comment: did you mean when open bottom popup the back page should not scroll?

Comment: I mean when we scroll inside that opened div, the body behind it should not scroll until we close down that opened div

Answer (score 2):

Body scroll effect can be removed through CSS Property, `overflow: hidden`

Create a CSS Class

```
.no-scroll
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

by using JQuery add this class to body when popup is open this will cause the body not to scroll.

```
$( "body" ).addClass( "no-scroll" );
```

remove it as soon as it closes down to make it scrollable again

```
$( "body" ).removeClass( "no-scroll" );
```

I hope this will work for you...

good luck!